# Firebase Cloud Functions: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation at Service

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a ReactJS web app that works with Firebase Cloud Functions.
Everything was running fine for a long time until I recently started doing some maintenance on the code and suddenly all of the Callable functions are giving me this error:

> Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation at Service

It doesn't execute any server code so it's on the client, I am not sure what else to try. I am able to invoke the functions from GCP without any problems.

EDIT:

TL:DR; Firebase version 7.22.x was breaking the fetch call for me. Any version prior to that (I tested as low as 7.5.x) worked without any problems.

So after debugging more and more, I decided to work with more restricted versions in my package.json.
At first I was suspecting that either Firebase, React or TS might be breaking something.

I started playing with Firebase versions. In my package.json, I was using Minor Versioning with the version set to ^7.5.0.
I restricted the versioning further by using Patch Versioning (~7.5.0) and all the sudden, this error was gone!

To pin-point which version was the trouble (also I wanted to use the latest I can), I started incrementing the versions up to the most recent (7.22.x at this time).
I found out that the latest version that works for me was ~7.11 and that's where I am gonna stay at until the root cause is fixed.

Comment: To get more context, is there more information from the error message like line numbers or file names?

Comment: @MrTech Unfortunately, there isn't. I had to place breakpoints inside Firebase code to even understand this is the actual message. In their code they wrap the fetch call with try catch and just return a generic message "Internal" so it was very time consuming to even get to that one...

Comment: @MrTech I tried to debug a bit more to find more info, this is all I got using Chrome DevTools:
Line 190 in service.ts. You can get there by tracing the invocation of the callable function

Comment: I hit the same problem, @MaxGlukhov. Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 0):

It appears fixed (based on their release notes) in 7.22.1 and later:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7221_-_october_5_2020